# Azure function .zip upload

Tags: azure, .net-core, cloud, blob, azure-blob-trigger

I am trying to fix an Azure function that is reading the stream from blob storage for uploded folders and its files. I am trying to add code for reading the contents/file name from a uploaded zipped folder.

I have two issues:

**Issue #1**: I was able to debug the Azure run method twice, but now it is not reading any more. I think it reads only once, but it read only normal folders once but ignored zipped one.

How to make it so the Azure function will read the same folders for debugging purpose,  any help?

**Issue #2**: the code reads normal folder at least once, but ignores zipped folder. I am not able to figure out like how to access and read a specific zipped folder?

I get the following while running and I'm not able to hit a breakpoint in the run method:

```
FileFunction: blobTrigger

ListsFunction: timerTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-04-25T03:02:40.519Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000UI906F5'.
```

Sample code :

```
[FunctionName("FileFunction")]
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("ContainerName/{folder}/{name}", Connection = "AzureJobsStorage")] Stream stream, string folder, string name, IDictionary<string, string> metadata)
{
    string fileName;

    Log.Information("'{name}' was uploaded to folder '{folder}'.", name, folder);

    // Check for zipped folder
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream))
    {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            fileName = entry.FullName; //trying to read zip file
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> the code reads normal folder at least once, but ignores zipped folder. I am not able to figure out like how to access and read a specific zipped folder

I noticed that the code to read the contents of the zip file is missing in your code. To read the contents of the zip file, you need to access the `Stream` of each `ZipArchiveEntry` and read its contents.

Use the below code to check if the uploaded file is .zip file or normal file and read the contents of that particular file.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Blobtriggerfunction
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{folder}/{name}", Connection = "demo")] Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
           //checking if the file is .zip 
            if (name.EndsWith(".zip"))
            {
            //code to read the contents of .zip file.
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(myBlob))
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        log.LogInformation($"File name: {entry.FullName}");
                        using (Stream stream = entry.Open())
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            log.LogInformation($"File contents: {contents}");
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //if the file is not .zip file
            else
            {
            //code to read the contents of .zip file.
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myBlob))
                {
                    string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    log.LogInformation($"File contents: {contents}");
                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Uploading .zip file to folder in blob:**
[image]

**Reading contents of recently uploaded .zip file:**
[image]

**Uploading normal(.txt) file to folder in blob:**
[image]

**Reading contents of recently uploaded .txt file:**
[image]